# Xamarin Forms Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application I need to add a bottom navigation bar in every pages. Bottom navigation bar should have 7 buttons and tapping on each buttons should navigate to corresponding pages. Is there any way to implement this in Xamarin forms?

Comment: [Tabbed Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/) sounds similar to your desired functionality. But I think it still puts Android tabs are the top. You might need to implement your own custom page or use a custom renderer on Android to change the placement. Try something and come back with more specific problems. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have implemented this using this plugin [Bottom Bar Plugin](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) it is a very useful plugin which renders tab bars at the bottom of the screen for android and IOS. Even though all the documentation you will need is available via the link I mention, the stackoverflow bots will swarm me unless I add that you can navigate to the site in question by searching google for

> BottomNavigationBarXF

other than cutting and pasting their documentation for the benefit of this site (so that anyone referrring to this answer in the event of a thermo nuclear war, after which stackoverflow is the only surviving site, can still contextualise this answer), I would urge you to consult their documentation which is well put together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tab page itself. For iOS, by default tab pages button are at bottom. For Android, there is a way to move the tabs to bottom. You need to update Xamarin or Visual Studio. After updating, add the below page directives to the Tab page Xaml code.

```
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
```

For example:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#a39d9f"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#007aff"
        android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="false"
        x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
<local:TodayPage />
<NavigationPage Title="Schedule" Icon="schedule.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:SchedulePage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```